# Change the default "Add project files." message in Visual Studio when creating a GIT repository

Tags: visual-studio, git-commit, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to edit the default commit message that Visual Studio uses when **first creating a repository** from inside the GIT menu.

By default it matches the language of the computer.
For example in English it's "Add project files." In Italian it's "Aggiungere i file di progetto."
[Screenshot of a test repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hNd3.png)

**Is there a way to change this message once and for all?**

<s>The worst thing is, by default VS pushes the commit to GitHub when creating a repository, so you can't use git amend locally.

I have searched the whole web for this issue, and all solutions seem to involve git rebase commands.</s>
*Found the "create only local" option, now I can use git amend.*
It works, but I'd like to avoid doing that everytime because it's time consuming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't push the commit, then use the command line to amend the commit to edit the message `git commit --amend`

Comment: @Richard Thanks a lot, now I found the button to create a local repo so that I can use amend. But I would still prefer it to be done by default by VS if possible

Comment: Git itself does not force any particular initial commit (`git init` makes a *completely empty* repository, with literally no branches and no commits in it) so this initial commit must be a VS-specific feature. (It helps avoid having to explain to users how to make the first commit, which is otherwise a little bit special.)

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong tag, I will get better with time